# How to use user input in form_tag for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rendered a form in one of my .erb templates and I am trying to grab the user input to pass to the route path...

```
<div class="dash-row" id="top-bar">
        <h2>Dashboard <span>Welcome back, </span></h2>
        <%= form_tag(single_path(params[:id]), :method => "get") do %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:id, placeholder="Search By Ticker")%>
            <%= submit_tag("Search")%>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

However, I get an error saying that the single_path is missing required keys: [:id]. The route is to an HTTParty.get API request in my controller which requires the "id" in the request url in order to receive the correct info.

How does this work if I'm getting errors for missing id? Can I pass user input to route paths via forms?

My controller:

```
def single
    params[:id]
    quote = HTTParty.get("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/#
   {params[:id]}/quote?displayPercent=true")


    def jsonParse(result)
        return JSON.parse result.to_s, symbolize_names: true
    end

    @quote = jsonParse(quote)
end
```

Comment: `params[:id]` must be present in the current request otherwise you are calling `single_path(nil)`. What is that you are trying to build?

Comment: I am basically building a stock search utilizing an exchange's api that can return all sorts of data on a particular stock. I edited to add my controller code...